# MLE of Multivariate Normal Distribution

Tags: matrices, statistics, parameter-estimation, maximum-likelihood

Let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a random sample from a multivariate normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and covariance matrix $\Sigma$. I want to show that
$$
\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}\quad\text{ and }\quad\hat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}(x_i-\mu)'(x_i-\mu)
$$
are the maximum likelihood estimators, i.e. I want to show that
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{p}{2}}\det(\Sigma)^{\frac{1}{2}}}exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}(x_i-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\bigg) 
=\frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{np}{2}}\det(\Sigma)^{\frac{n}{2}}}exp\bigg(-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(x_i-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\bigg)
\end{align}
is maximized by $\hat{\mu}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}$ defined above.
We first check for the minimizer of $\mu$. For this only the second part of the term is interesting. I do the trace trick:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n\bigg(x_i-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \bigg)
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg( tr\Big((x_i-\mu)'\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)\Big)\bigg)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg( tr\Big(\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu)(x_i-\mu)'\Big)\bigg)\\
&= \sum_{i=1}^n\bigg( tr\Big(\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\bar{x}+\bar{x}-\mu)(x_i-\bar{x}+\bar{x}-\mu)'\Big)\bigg)\\
&=  tr\bigg(\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\Big((x_i-\bar{x}+\bar{x}-\mu)(x_i-\bar{x}+\bar{x}-\mu)'\Big)\bigg)\\
&=  tr\bigg(\Sigma^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\Big((x_i-\bar{x})(x_i-\bar{x})'\Big)+n(\bar{x}-\mu)(\bar{x}-\mu)'\bigg),\\
\end{align}
where I used in the last step that the cross terms cancel each other out. It es now easy to see that the maximizer of $\mu$ is given by $\hat{\mu}=\bar{x}$. But I could not prove that $\Sigma$ is maximized by $\hat{\Sigma}=\frac{1}{n}(x_i-\mu)'(x_i-\mu)$. I would be glad for any help.

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Are trying to put these expressions directly into the likelihood function and then argue by inspection? If so I suspect the presence of an inverse and a determinant of $\Sigma$ are going to make that a nightmare - a more conventional approach is using calculus and the log-likelihood function